# Can't access Ingress from Kubernetes node

Tags: docker, kubernetes, minikube, harbor

I have a CentOS machine where I created a Kubernetes cluster:

`minikube start --driver=docker --addons ingress`.

Inside the cluster, I installed a Harbor instance using a Helm chart using:

`helm install harbor-release harbor/harbor --set expose.type=ingress`

In the CentOS machine, I added an entry to my /etc/hosts pointing to the new ingress:

`echo "$(minikube ip)  core.harbor.domain" >> /etc/hosts`

And with this, I can access to Harbor from this machine. I can login using Firefox and I'm able to push some custom images:

```
docker pull python
docker tag docker.io/python core.harbor.domain:443/library/python:latest
docker login https://core.harbor.domain --username admin --password Harbor12345
docker push core.harbor.domain:443/library/python:latest
```

And we are all happy. My problem starts when I try to deploy another Helm chart using those images. Kubernetes is not able to pull the images and timeouts. After some tries, I find out that my minikube node is not able to connect to Harbor.

I tried adding to /etc/hosts different IPs like 127.0.0.1, `minikube ip`, etc without any results. Docker can never do a pull. If I use 127.0.0.1 I'm able to do a `curl -k https://core.harbor.domain` but not a `docker login`.

I also tried adding core.harbor.domain to docker insecure registries but without any luck.

Maybe I'm missing something and I shouldn't be able to access the ingress url from my minikube node in the first place.

- What could I be doing wrong?
- Do you think it's a good approach to put Harbor and the application pods in the same cluster?

Comment: Its your local env or this Centos is on Virtual app (VM Vare, VritualBox)? Did you change anything in firewall rules?

Comment: Indeed, it's on VirtualBox. So actually I have: Windows host -> (VirtualBox) -> Centos VM -> (minikube --driver=docker) -> Node. I didn't change any firewall and the connection between Windows and the VM is through a Host-only adapter. I guess it shouldn't affect it since the VM is able to access the Docker registry.